# How to summon potions on the ground in minecraft 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to summon potions with effects on the ground in an area with 1.9. I had a command that worked in 1.8:

```
/summon Item 343 5 -641 {Item:{id:373,Count:1,Damage:16452}}
```

But now it doesn't work because of IDs being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Damage` tag no longer holds the type of default potion. Instead, the `Potion` string within the `tag` compound states the name ID of the default potion.

As well, you should **not** be using numerical IDs for items since 1.8 and should have instead been using name IDs. In 1.9, numerical IDs are no longer used.

```
/summon Item 343 5 -641 {Item:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:1b,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:healing"}}}
```

The wiki lists different potion IDs [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Item_data).

Comment: 1 last thing, how do i change it to ligering or spash?

Comment: @mrcreeper Change the ID from "potion" to "splash_potion" or "lingering_potion".